# Unable to reference response from Powershell cmdlet

Tags: powershell, dpm

I am attempting to gather some information about multiple DPM servers via powershell.

Firstly I assign the Protection Group I am interested in to **$pg**, then set the **$po** variable to the the Policy Objective information about that Protection Group

```
PS C:\> $pg = Get-DPMProtectionGroup -DPMServerName DPMserver | Where-Object {$_.FriendlyName -eq "BMR protection"}

PS C:\> $po = Get-DPMPolicyObjective -ProtectionGroup $pg -shortterm
```

Finally I type **$po** interactively at the console and get this response:

```
PS C:\> $po

Retention Range                                             Synchronization Frequency
---------------                                             -------------------------
15 day(s)                                                   Before recovery point
```

Now the information I am interested in is listed under the "Synchronization Frequency" column. However I have no idea how to reference this!

I assumed it would be a Property of the **$po** object... but as you can see below that is not the case.

Am I missing something obvious here? Where is the value of "Synchronization Frequency" stored?

```
PS C:\> $po | Get-Member -MemberType properties

       TypeName: Microsoft.Internal.EnterpriseStorage.Dls.UI.ObjectModel.OMCommon.OnsiteIntentGenerator

    Name              MemberType Definition
    ----              ---------- ----------
    AllowIncrementals Property   System.Boolean AllowIncrementals {get;}
    Frequency         Property   Microsoft.Internal.EnterpriseStorage.Dls.UI.ObjectModel.OMCommon.BackupFrequency Freque...
    IncrementalSet    Property   System.Boolean IncrementalSet {get;}
    Interval          Property   System.Int32 Interval {get;}
    Mode              Property   System.Boolean Mode {get;}
    RecoveryRange     Property   Microsoft.Internal.EnterpriseStorage.Dls.UI.ObjectModel.OMCommon.RetentionRange Recover...
    Schedules         Property   System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Microsoft.Internal.EnterpriseStorage.Dls.UI.ObjectMo...
```

Comment: Is there a return from  `$po."Synchronization Frequency"`

Comment: @Matt thanks, i actually tried that already - but unfortunately it does not return anything: `PS C:\> $po."Synchronization Frequency"   
PS C:\>`

Comment: Another shot in the dark then. Is it possible what you are looking for is a different `membertype`? What about `$po | Get-Member`

Comment: @Matt - there are a few methods -> see [pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/j862TqgL)

Comment: If no one else knows this will help lead you to the default property set. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2010/02/18/psstandardmembers-the-stealth-property.aspx. If I had to guess it is `Schedules` since it is a list. That might be the property it is displaying by default